# Ring of endomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a simple $R$-module. My goal is to show that End$_R(M)$ is a field. I have proven a version of Schur's Lemma. That is, I have proven to myself that a homomorphism $\phi: M \rightarrow M'$ of simple $R$ -modules is either an isomorphism or the zero-morphism.

This version of Schur's Lemma immediately implies that End$_R(M)$ is a division ring. My problem arises with proving that End$_R(M)$ is commutative. I don't immediately see why End$_R(M)$ is commutative, and I was not given any information about $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly right that $\text{End}_R(M)$ is (in general) only a division ring. However, we can use the fact that $R$ is commutative to learn more.

In particular, if $M$ is a simple $R$ module, then $M \cong R/\mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

But can you show that every endomorphism of $R / I$ looks like multiplication by $r$ for some $r \in R$? (Hint: if $\varphi$ is your endomorphism, look at $\varphi(1)$).

Then there is a surjection $R \to \text{End}_R(M)$. What is its kernel? Do you see why this shows $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a field?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: It does thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With no further hypotheses this is not true; Schur's lemma tells you that $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a division ring (and slightly more precisely it's a division algebra over $Z(R)$) and that's all. Moreover every noncommutative division ring occurs, e.g. if $R$ itself is a division ring $D$ and $M = D$ is the regular representation, in which case $\text{End}_D(D) \cong D^{op}$.

It is true if $R$ is commutative; for this you can show that we have $M \cong R/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal, and then show that $\text{End}_R(R/m) \cong R/m$. It is worth thinking in some detail about the case that $R = k[x]$ for $k$ a field and $m = (f(x))$ is the maximal ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Is there a specific Isomorphism I can consider from $\text{End}_R(R/m) \rightarrow R/m$?

Comment: I believe that I can show that if $R$ is commutative;  then we have $M \cong R/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen: yes, evaluation at $1$, although it's not obvious that this is even a ring homomorphism. I think it's easier to think about the map in the other direction, $R/m \to \text{End}_R(R/m)$, which is just the action by left (or right) multiplication, and which is obviously a ring homomorphism. Then you show that this map is an isomorphism.

Comment: When you say " action by left (or right) multiplication" what exactly am i multiplying?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen: $R/m$ is a quotient ring, so it has a multiplication map $R/m \times R/m \to R/m$.